# Xamarin WaitingForActivation

Tags: android, rest, xamarin

I have a problem with WaitingForActivation status of the service call;

My code

```
Public async Task CallService(string path)
    {
        IRestClient client = new RestClient(config.Ip);
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(config.MainResources + path, Method.GET);

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                var response = client.Execute<List<string>>(request);

            });  

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

But respons is still status of WaitingForActivation.

Do you know where could be issue ?
Or do you have any better idea to make async method which returns me response from rest service?

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a scope problem. In C# if you execute codes like below:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnClick;
    int response;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
        btnClick.Click += BtnClick_Click;
    }

    private async void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int response = 123456;// should be response=123456;
        });

        var abc = response;//response is 0
    }
}
```

the codes inside `Task.Run` get executed correctly. But the response is still 0; You need to remove the `int` inside the `Task.Run` block.

If it is not the case, it is most likely the problem of service call (the request might be wrong, or the service might return the wrong response and so on), which can't be tell from your posted codes, need a basic demo for that.